# should call function inside ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to angular testing , I would like to know how can i test the function that have been called when ngOnInit called . Below is the code that i am trying to test

```
it('should call TestMethod method inside ngOnInit' , async() => {
    spyOn(component , 'TestMethod')
    fixture.detectChanges()
    expect(component.TestMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

Below is the error i am getting

```
Expected spy TestMethod to have been called.
```

BeforeEach is below

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateRoomsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: is TestMethod private? if so do spyOn<any>(component , 'TestMethod')

Comment: Its a public function .

Comment: okay you need to add .and.callthrough() to bypass it.

Comment: Like this spyOn(component , 'TestMethod').and.callthrough() ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the spy object to a variable and use that variable in expect function

```
    it('should call TestMethod method inside ngOnInit' , async() => {
    const obj = spyOn(component , 'TestMethod')
    fixture.detectChanges()
    expect(obj).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

Comment: Getting this below :
Expected spy TestMethod to have been called.
Error: Expected spy TestMethod to have been called.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it is working .

```
it('should call TestMethod method inside ngOnInit' , async() => {
    const obj = spyOn(component , 'TestMethod')
    component.ngOnInit()
    expect(obj).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```